# Interpolating an expression in GitHub Action

Tags: github-actions

I'm using the `mshick/add-pr-comment` GitHub action which sends a message to a PR.

Instead of sending a static text (like in the example), I need to have a dynamic message which is the result of the following expression:
`cat rs/coverage/.last_run.json | jq '.result.line'`

How can I interpolate such an expression?

I have tried but it sends the exact string and not the result of it.

```
- uses: mshick/add-pr-comment@v1
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
   with:
     message: $(cat reaction6/coverage/.last_run.json | jq '.result.line')
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try first set vairable and then use it:

```yaml
- name: Create PR message
  run: echo "msg=$(cat reaction6/coverage/.last_run.json | jq '.result.line')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
- uses: mshick/add-pr-comment@v1
  env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
   with:
     message: "${{ env.msg}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. that may probably work. I was able to send the message using the `set-output` syntax GitHub provides. See more here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter.

Comment: For future readers: `set-output` was deprecated on 2022-10-11, so the answer shows the correct way to set output parameters.